# Image byte array is not saving properly to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save an image to a database table, but it doesn't save the whole byte array for some reason and I can't figure out why.

This is what my table looks like after trying to insert a byte array.

[image: database table]

The data column is set to varbinary(MAX).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfilePictures] (
    [Id]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Data]   VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
);
```

This is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetProfilePicture]
    @Image VARBINARY,
    @UserId INT
AS
    INSERT INTO ProfilePictures (UserId, [Data])
    VALUES (@UserId, @Image)
RETURN 0
```

Here is my code. The image parameter has the correct data.

[image: Byte array]

```
_connection.SqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SetProfilePicture", _connection.SqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, profilePicture.Image.Length).Value = profilePicture.Image;
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", user.Id);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
_connection.SqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Please post your table def/sample, query and code as text, instead of a image.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: What data type is `profilePicture.Image`?

Comment: You probably need to convert the image to `byte[]` because that wont happen automatically

Comment: ProfilePicture.Image is a byte[].

Comment: Would it not be better and less overhead to store the image on a drive (cloud, local, server) and just store the path to the image in the database?  Since images can be quite large it could lead to some DB performance issues later on.

Comment: The missing scale of your varbinary which causes this issues is one of the more frustrating things about sql server. For datatypes like varbinary, char, varchar the scale should be required and no default for it being omitted. It would save so many headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default length of `varbinary` is 1 if the length isn't specified.  See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The default length is 1 when n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetProfilePicture]
    @Image VARBINARY,
```

needs to be given a length, as such:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetProfilePicture]
    @Image VARBINARY(max),
```